# computed properties not getting updated

Tags: ember.js

**Problem: the computed property "tnop" does not get updated when the controller modifies the "pages" array as shown below:**

### relevant book model code:

```
sections: []
tnop: function() 
{
var n = 0;
var sections = this.get('sections');
if (!sections)
  return n;

for (var i=0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  n += sections[i].pages.length;
}
return n;
}.property('sections.@each.pages.length')
```

---

### relevant controller code:

```
var sections = EM.model.getPath('book.sections');
var aps = EM.model.getPath("ps");
$.each(sections, function(si, section) {
  var bp = [];
  if (json && json.ia) {
    bp = section.get("pages");
    var ns = aps[json.ssi];

      var lp = ns.get("lp");
      var rp = ns.get("rp");
    if (rp) {
      bp.insertAt(lp.number-1, rp);
      bp[lp.number-1] = rp;
    }
    if (lp) {
      bp.insertAt(lp.number-1, lp);
      bp[lp.number-1] = lp;
    }
  }
});
```

---

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands, you can't observe deeply nested paths off @each directly. Instead, you have to use nested @each proxies, as such:

property('sections.@each.pages.@each.length')

Comment: What's happening is that when the observing code plucks 'pages' off of @ each, it gets another array, and so to observe properties on objects inside that array you need to observe off @ each for THAT array, hence the nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem solved using with following code:

```
filters: [],
content: [],

filterFun: function()
{

}.property('content.@each', 'filters.@each').cacheable(),
```